# C++ allocates previously reserved memory when using new Obj2() inside constructor of Obj1?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, memory-corruption

I have a Class "Grid" which declares a 2-dimensional array of pointers to objects of class "Cell" as property. When I instantiate an object of "Grid" I see in the debugger, that the constructor's code which initializes  the array calling "new Cell(p1, p2)" inside a loop produces pointers to Cells which lie inside the allocation for the array, thus corrupting the array of pointers.

Here some extracts of the code:

```
class Cell {
    public:
        Cell( int a, int b );
}
class Grid {
    public:
          Grid(); 
          Cell * g[6][7];
}

// code:

Grid::Grid() {
  // g is allocated to address x'13d1-19b8 (extending for 42*4=168 bytes)
    for ( int r=0; r<6; r++ )
    {
        for ( int c=0; c<7; c++ )
        {
            g[r][c] = new Cell( r, c );  // g[0][0] now contains x'13d1-19d8 which is INSIDE g[][] !?!?!
        }
     }
.....
}
```

Can anybody tell me what's going on or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the constructor for `Cell`?

Comment: Violation of the rule of three (five C++11), avoid multidimensional arrays

Comment: For the purpose of finding the error I reduced the constructor of Cell to: 
Cell::Cell( int r, int c )
{
  row = r;
  col = c;
}
where row and col are properties of Cell

Comment: can anyone explain @Dieter 's comment? (Should we go back to assembler??)

Comment: You're creating an object which owns dynamically allocated data, created in the constructor. That part's fine. What's not fine is that you don't appear to define a custom copy constructor and `operator=` -- which means the compiler-generated default ones are being used, and they don't know about your class's semantics, they just blindly copy `g` from instance to instance, leading to multiple frees and use-after-free of the allocated data. That is the rule of three (if you define one of those three methods in a special way, chances are you should define the other two to match).

Comment: Thank you @Cameron for your explanation. Unfortunately I still don't get it. Which of the "three" am I using? Which statement is copying g or anyother Object? The way I read my code, I only assign pointers to pointers. Can you explain a little more for someone who is not very hot on C++ (I admit I prefer Java)?

Comment: @Mark: You should look up one of the many tutorials on the subject, as it's likely to be better explained than whatever I can squeeze into this comment; but in your case, you've defined a custom constructor (1 of 3), but not a custom copy constructor (2 of 3) or assignment operator (3 of 3). In the code you've posted, there's no copying of `Grid` objects, but given that C++ is based heavily around copying objects and the problem you're having, there's almost certainly a copy going on somewhere in your code. The copying of `g` itself is done in the compiler-generated copy constructor...

Comment: ... and operator=, and it's a problem because it copies just the pointer values; when the old object is then destroyed I assume you have a destructor that frees the memory pointed to by the pointers, but the problem then is that *another object (the copied-into one) now thinks it owns the same pointers, even though they've just been freed*. Edit: Seems I've messed up the rule of three, sorry :P The custom constructor isn't one of the three, rather the custom destructor -- but, in your case (manual memory management with symmetrical allocs and deallocs in the ctor/dtor), it works out the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've rebuilt the project piece by piece, trying to descover which part of the code causes the corruption. However I couldn't reproduce the error. I now have what looks to my eye an identical copy of the original code and it works just fine. (The original one still fails.) Can't see where I made the mistake in the first attempt, but I'm happy to be able to progress.

Thanks to those (@Cameron) who tried to help and maybe some day @Dieter will explain to me why he down-voted my question...  ;)